# go block hangs indefinitely with core.sync

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, core.async

Here is the code:

```
(ns typed-clj-test.async
  (:require [clojure.core.async
             :as a
             :refer [>! <! >!! <!!
                     go chan buffer
                     close! thread
                     alts! alts!! timeout]]))

(def echo-buffer (chan 2))
(go (do (<! (timeout 5000))
        (println (<! echo-buffer))))
(>!! echo-buffer "msg1")
(>!! echo-buffer "msg2")
(>!! echo-buffer "msg3")
(>!! echo-buffer "msg4")
```

This hangs forever after printing msg1 in nrepl:

```
typed-clj-test.async=> (def echo-buffer (chan 2))
#'typed-clj-test.async/echo-buffer
typed-clj-test.async=> (go (do (<! (timeout 5000))
                  #_=>         (println (<! echo-buffer))))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@6cc648a>
typed-clj-test.async=> (>!! echo-buffer "msg1")
true
typed-clj-test.async=> (>!! echo-buffer "msg2")
true
typed-clj-test.async=> (>!! echo-buffer "msg3")
msg1
true
typed-clj-test.async=> (>!! echo-buffer "msg4")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only ever getting the first message out of the echo-buffer, and since the buffer size is 2, trying to add a fourth message to the buffer will block until another value is removed from the buffer (which will never happen).

In other words, you seem to expect that

```
(go (do (<! (timeout 5000))
        (println (<! echo-buffer))))
```

loops, but it won't.

Here is how to make it work:

```
(def echo-buffer (chan 2))
(go (do (loop [i 0]
          (<! (timeout (* 100 (rand-int 20))))
          (println (<! echo-buffer))
          (recur i))))
(>!! echo-buffer "msg1")
(>!! echo-buffer "msg2")
(>!! echo-buffer "msg3")
(>!! echo-buffer "msg4")
```